# EntityFramework - select entity with custom property projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression, expression-trees

Consider following entity:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get;  set; }
}
```

**I'd like to round any `decimal` value before assigning to model instance.** I'd could do it in this way:

```
dbContext.Models
             .Select(model => new 
                    { 
                      Id = model.Id, 
                      Value = Math.Round(model.Value, 10) 
                    }
             .ToList()
             .Select(anonymous => 
                          new Model 
                              { 
                                Id = anonymous.Id
                                Value = anonymous.Value
                              });
```

It works fine, but I've a entity that contains over 100 columns. Is it possible to build projection that automatically iterate throgh properties and call `Math.Round` on `decimal` properties and create entity model instance with new values?

I don't want implementation - only clue if it possible to do ith with expresion tree or should look for other solution.

Comment: This is surely possible with reflection.

Comment: I know, but it must be build with ExpressionTrees in order to allow Entity framwoork translate it into sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do this using expression trees. What I would do is to write a class that inherits from [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor), override its [`VisitMember()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.visitmember) method and in there check for `decimal` properties. When you detect a `decimal` property, return that property wrapped in `Math.Round()`.

The end result should be exactly what you want: a lambda expression like `model => new { Id = model.Id, Value = model.Value }` will be transformed into `model => new { Id = model.Id, Value = Math.Round(model.Value, 10) }`. You can then call this from an extension method called something like `SelectRounded()`.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try. Hope that EF do not throw `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: What's more, I see it like `dbContext.Models.RoundDecimals().ToList()`. Anyway - customer `ExpressionVisitor` will be accepted by EF?

Comment: @pwas If you do it correctly, EF will never see the `ExpressionVisitor`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rounding the values each time, it is better to store values rounded.
You need to specify the decimal rounding in the `OnModelCreating` function:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().Property(x => x.Value).HasPrecision(10, 8);
}
```

Comment: It's external Database. Cannot affect the schema or data. I've only `SELECT` execution permission.